# Is there way I can SELECT and JOIN COUNT different queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MYSQL and I have a message table like below.

| id | parent_id | sender_id | receiver_id | content | readed | sender_deleted | receiver_deleted | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 0 | 6 | 1 | testab | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 01:13:42 |
| 19 | 18 | 6 | 1 | testcd | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 01:14:55 |

I'm trying to combine two queries in one. Selecting and count where readed value is 0.

This query is selecting query.

```
SELECT * FROM message 
    WHERE (sender_id = 1 OR receiver_id = 1) AND (id = 18 OR parent_id = 18);
```

And this query is counting query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM message 
     WHERE (sender_id = 1 OR receiver_id = 1) 
       AND (id = 18 OR parent_id = 18) AND (readed = 0);
```

I'm trying to combine these two using LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.content, COUNT(b.id) AS unreaded_message 
  FROM message a 
  LEFT JOIN message c ON a.id = c.id AND (readed = 0) 
 GROUP BY A.ID, A.Date 
 ORDER BY a.id;
```

But I'm getting error like below.

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'b.id' in 'field list'
```

Is there way I can left join count query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice these issues when testing the query:

1. The incorrect alias of `b.id` for the `COUNT()`. That's where the error is indicating.
2. The non-existing `A.Date` from table `message`. Based on your table sample, you don't have a column named as `Date`. Instead you have a column named `created` that stores date+time.
3. The query itself is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. Since MySQL v5.7.5, this setting is on by default, with a very good reason of - "if the `only_full_group_by` mode is turned off  *the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want* (refer: ["MySQL Handling of Group By" docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Now, if I'm not mistaken, `content` stores the text messages, correct? And since `id=19` parent is `id=18`, it should be in the same row, with the total count of unread   message is `2`. I'm not sure if that's what you're really looking for but I'll post two queries; one is to address your current issue and another to suggest that it maybe what you're looking for.

For your current issue, you can achieve the desired result without self-join, and instead of using `COUNT()`, you can use `SUM()` with `CASE` expression like below:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, content, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN readed=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unreaded_message
FROM message
GROUP BY id, parent_id, content;
```

`COUNT()` will take every row in the query result depending on your conditions. The replacement of `SUM()` with `CASE` expression here is just telling the query to:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN readed=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unreaded_message
   -- if the readed column is 0 (zero) then give it 1, else give it 0 then add them up.
```

The second suggestion I have is this, let's assume you have more rows in the table like this:

| id | parent_id | sender_id | receiver_id | content | readed | sender_deleted | receiver_deleted | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 0 | 6 | 1 | testab | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 01:13:42 |
| 19 | 18 | 6 | 1 | testcd | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 01:14:55 |
| 20 | 18 | 6 | 1 | testde | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 01:15:05 |
| 21 | 0 | 6 | 1 | testfg | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 02:34:11 |
| 22 | 21 | 6 | 1 | testhi | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-28 02:44:01 |

With `id` of `18,19` both have `readed=1`, the query you have and the one I suggested above will return result like this:

| id | parent_id | content | unreaded_message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 0 | testab | 0 |
| 19 | 18 | testcd | 0 |
| 20 | 18 | testde | 1 |
| 21 | 0 | testfg | 1 |
| 22 | 21 | testhi | 1 |

But I have a feeling that you probably want something like this:

| m_id | contents | unreaded_message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | testde | 1 |
| 21 | testgf testhi | 2 |

If that's a possibility, then you can just run this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN parent_id=0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END AS m_id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN readed=0 
                          THEN content ELSE '' END 
                      ORDER BY readed, id SEPARATOR '\r\n' ) AS contents,
        SUM(CASE WHEN readed=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unreaded_message
FROM message
GROUP BY m_id;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26c2f027cd7a61d51adfcee7129764be)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are using in the query B alias in the  "COUNT" satement. You need to use A or C alias like these example:

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.content, COUNT(c.id) AS unreaded_message 
FROM message a 
LEFT JOIN message c ON a.id = c.id AND (readed = 0) 
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Date 
ORDER BY a.id;
```